How can I remove unintended localization of the Force Quit Applications dialog?
Last Friday I updated my MacBook Pro (16", Nov '23) to macOS Sequoia (15.0). The OS language is English, but since the update, the body of the Force Quit Applications dialog is in Dutch:

My region is set to The Netherlands, but even if I change that to United Kingdom, the issue persists. How can I change this behaviour?

It looks similar to this very old issue but I never had Dutch configured in my system, and in that screenshot the dialog title is also translated.
I noticed it appears on the log out dialog and log in screen as well:

It might be related to the machine being set up by our company's help desk. I have removed that user, but the problem still persists.
